# 'ValueError: variable name is not valid in MATLAB' when extracting the results stored in MATLAB workspace after excecuting Simulink model using python

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, simulink, workspace, connector

I would like to control my Simulink model using Python. I have written a Python script for it. My simulink model name is  = 'ToyExample_V2'. The model is shown below in the picture attached.

[image]

In this model, using Python, I want to give '1' as an input value to the constant block and I would like to run the simulation for 10 seconds with the timestep value 0.1. At the end of the simulation, I would like to see the results stored the workspace which has variable stored as a name 'simout'.

In this model, using Python, I want to give '1' as an input value to the constant block and I would like to run the simulation for 10 seconds with the timestep value 0.1. At the end of the simulation, I would like to see the results stored the workspace which has variable stored as a name 'simout'.

In order to extract the results from Matlab workspace, I have written a Function (method) in the Python as shown below:

```
def getOutput(self):
    simout_S = self.eng.workspace['out.simout']
    tout_T = self.eng.workspace['out.tout']
    return simout_S, tout_T
```

However, after running the code, I am getting the error 'variable name is not valid in MATLAB' as shown below:
[image]

How can I solve this error / How can I extract results stored in the MATLAB workspace in python?